# Multiline regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How do I match and replace text using regular expressions in multiline mode?

I know the [RegexOptions.Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) option, but what is the best way to specify match all with the new line characters in C#?

Input:

```
<tag name="abc">this
is
a
text</tag>
```

Output:

```
[tag name="abc"]this
is
a
test
[/tag]
```

---

Aahh, I found the actual problem. '&' and ';' in Regex are matching text in a single line, while the same need to be escaped in the Regex to work in cases where there are new lines also.

Comment: Huh? & and ; are no special characters in regex. Can you give an example?

Comment: Something similar, though haven't tried the below ex.
rx.Replace("name[=]&quot;abc&quot;", "abc", "multiline text");

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you mean there *has* to be a newline character for the expression to match, then `\n` will do that for you.

Otherwise, I think you might have misunderstood the [Multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Multiline)/[Singleline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#Singleline) flags. If you want your expression to match across several lines, you actually want to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`. What it means is that it treats the entire input string as a single line, thus ignoring newlines. Is this what you're after...?

**Example**

```
Regex rx = new Regex("<tag name=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</tag>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
String output = rx.Replace("Text <tag name=\"abc\">test\nwith\nnewline</tag> more text...", "[tag name=\"$1\"]$2[/tag]");
```

Comment: I want to match some text that may contain new line characters also, but not necessarily. Now, if you say with RegexOptions.Singleline, then can you show me an example on how to do this.

Comment: see my edit for an example. I seem to have been mistaken about it being default tho, when I tested it... manually specifying singleline as in the example, makes the example work, tho

Comment: thanks, it looks like the problem was different, but thanks for clearing my doubts about multiline mode.

Comment: Ah! I was banging my head after using the .MultiLine enum value! It wasn't matching over multiple lines that way :DOH: Thanks very much for the explanation! Guess I should have read the doc tooltip in VS first . . .

Answer (score 16):

Here's a regex to match.  It requires the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, which makes the `.` match newlines.

```
<(\w+) name="([^"]*)">(.*?)</\1>
```

After this regex, the first group contains the tag, the second the tag name, and the third the content between the tags.  So replacement string could look like this:

```
[$1 name="$2"]$3[/$1]
```

In C#, this looks like:

```
newString = Regex.Replace(oldString, 
    @"<(\w+) name=""([^""]*)"">(.*?)</\1>", 
    "[$1 name=\"$2\"]$3[/$1]", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: +1: Very good code and explanation.
@Priyank Bolia: Just remember that this works only if <tag>s can't be nested. If they *can* be, then regular expressions will fail you.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent example, i figured out, it was some other issue though.