# Replace text which contain line breaks without dropping them

Tags: c#

We have a text which goes like this ..

```
This is text
                i want
                to keep
                    but
                Replace this sentence
                because i dont like it.
```

Now i want to replace this sentence `Replace this sentence because i dont like it.`

Of course going like this

```
text = text.Replace(@"Replace this sentence because i dont like it.", "");
```

Wont solve my problem. **I can't drop line breaks and replace them with one line.**

My output should be

```
This is text
                i want
                to keep
                    but
```

Please keep in mind there is a lot variations and line breaks for sentence i don't like.

I.E it may go like

```
Replace this 
sentence
                    because i dont like it.
```

or

```
Some text before. Replace this 
    sentence
                        because i dont like it.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex to find any kind of whitespace. This includes regular spaces but also carriage returns and linefeeds as well as tabulators or half-spaces and so on.

```
string input = @"This is text
    i want
    to keep
        but
    Replace this sentence
    because i dont like it.";

string dontLike = @"Replace this sentence because i dont like it.";
string pattern = Regex.Escape(dontLike).Replace(@"\ ", @"\s+");

Console.WriteLine("Pattern:");
Console.WriteLine(pattern);

string clean = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Result:");
Console.WriteLine(clean);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
Pattern:
Replace\s+this\s+sentence\s+because\s+i\s+dont\s+like\s+it\.

Result:
This is text
                i want
                to keep
                    but
```

`Regex.Escape` escapes any character that would otherwise have a special meaning in Regex. E.g., the period `"."` means "any number of repetitions". It also replaces the spaces `" "` with `@"\ "`. We in turn replace `@"\ "` in the search pattern by `@"\s+"`. `\s+` in Regex means "one or more white spaces".

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to match "any whitespace" instead of just space in your search string. Roughly

- escape search string to be safe for regex -[Escape Special Character in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505914/escape-special-character-in-regex)
- replace spaces with `"\s+"` ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference))
- run regex matching multiple lines - [Multiline regular expression in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780009/multiline-regular-expression-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Or, use LINQ to accomplish this:

```
var text = "Drones " + Environment.NewLine + "are great to fly, " + Environment.NewLine + "yes, very fun!";
var textToReplace = "Drones are great".Split(" ").ToList();
textToReplace.ForEach(f => text = text.Replace(f, ""));
```

Output:

```
to fly, 

yes, very fun!
```

Whatever method you choose, you are going to deal with extra line breaks, too many spaces and other formatting issues... Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, if output format of string is optional here:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string textToReplace = @"Replace this sentence because i dont like it.";
        string text = @"This is text
                i want
                to keep
                    but
                Replace this sentence
                because i dont like it.";

        text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        text = text.Replace(textToReplace, string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"This is text i want to keep but"
```