# C# Regex to get text between two tags?

Tags: c#, regex

Alright, I'm having a bit of difficulty replacing text in this config file. The section I'm trying to replace...

```
    <!-- Executables we want to manage -->
  <KioskExecutables>
    <Executables>
      <add appName="Valet" exeName="365Valet.exe" startOrder="0" />
      <add appName="Sync" exeName="365Sync.exe" startOrder="1" />
      <add appName="Readiness" exeName="KioskReadiness.exe" startOrder="2" />
</Executables>
  </KioskExecutables>
```

I would like to swap out the text between the  tags. I wrote the following..

```
string matchCodeTag = @"<Executables>(.*?)</Executables>";
string textToReplace = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Controller.exe.config");
string replaceWith = "<add appName=\"Disable\" exeName=\"C:\\Temp\\Disable.exe\" startOrder=\"0\" />";
string output = Regex.Replace(textToReplace, matchCodeTag, replaceWith);
```

It doesn't seem to be picking up the match though, I believe because the newline characters but I'm not certain.

Could someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: [Please don't try to parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser instead.](//stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (same goes for XML)

Comment: It's safer to use `XDocument` or other xml library instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline regular expression in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780009/multiline-regular-expression-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you should use an `XmlDocument` to parse your config.

But if you must use regex you need to enable the Singleline option so that the dot character (.) matches newline characters as well e.g.

```
string matchCodeTag = @"<Executables>(.*)</Executables>";
string textToReplace = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Controller.exe.config");
string replaceWith = "<add appName=\"Disable\" exeName=\"C:\\Temp\\Disable.exe\" startOrder=\"0\" />";
string output = Regex.Replace(textToReplace, matchCodeTag, 
                              replaceWith, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

or you can set the option in the regex pattern like this

```
string matchCodeTag = @"(?s)<Executables>(.*)</Executables>";
```

Your pattern does not need the question mark as the * is already "zero or more matches"

Comment: "As commented, you should use an XmlDocument to parse your config." - I'd actually recommend using LINQ to XML (XDocument) rather than XmlDocument. It's generally a much nicer API.

Comment: I ended up using XmlDocument to parse it and it was very easy. I was aware I shouldn't use Regex for HTML but I hadn't read that about XML.